# Pagnation in Python (Beautifulsoup)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Python and whilst I have managed to scrape the first page I'm stuck as to how to move through the pagnation. Here's my code so far for the first page:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
books = soup.find("section")
book_list = books.find_all(class_="product_pod")


csvfile = csv.writer(open('books.csv', 'w', newline=''))
csvfile.writerow(['Title', 'Price', 'Stock', 'Link'])

for book in book_list:
    price = book.find(class_="price_color").get_text()
    title = book.select_one('a img')['alt']
    stock = book.find('p',attrs={"class":"instock availability"}).get_text().strip()
    link = "http://books.toscrape.com/" + book.find('a')['href']
    csvfile.writerow([title, price, stock, link])
```

Comment: You just want to iterate over all 50 pages? Looks like the URL format is: "http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{PAGENUMBER}.html" so you could probably just iterate from 1 to 50 in a for loop. If I'm understanding your goal correctly.

Comment: Correct, I'm just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to "hardcode" number of pages (in this case, 50). Or you could get next page "dynamically". That means search for "Next" button on current page, if exists, get the link and continue **scraping**. If "Next" button doesn't exist, stop running.

For example:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://books.toscrape.com/")

with open('books.csv', 'w') as f_out:   # books.csv
    csvfile = csv.writer(f_out)
    csvfile.writerow(['Title', 'Price', 'Stock', 'Link'])

    current_page = 1
    current_url = "http://books.toscrape.com/"

    while True:
        print('Processing page {}...'.format(current_page))

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        books = soup.find("section")
        book_list = books.find_all(class_="product_pod")

        for book in book_list:
            price = book.find(class_="price_color").get_text()
            title = book.select_one('a img')['alt']
            stock = book.find('p',attrs={"class":"instock availability"}).get_text().strip()
            link = "http://books.toscrape.com/" + book.find('a')['href']
            csvfile.writerow([title, price, stock, link])

        # is there "Next" button
        next_link = soup.select_one('li.next > a')

        if not next_link:
            # no, we're on last page, exit
            break

        # yes, continue:
        current_url = current_url.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[0] + '/' + next_link['href']
        page = requests.get(current_url)
        current_page += 1
```

Produces:

[image]